How to place an html block at the bottom of the last(!) page when printing with CSS and/or JS?
When printing from html, two pages are generated.
For visual learners:

CSS:
.footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: none; /* Initially hide the footer */
}

@media print {
  .footer {
    display: block; /* Show the footer when printing */
  }
}

HTML:
<div id="content">
  <h1>Your content here</h1>
  <p>A lot of "Lorem". Check sandbox (link place on bottom)</p>
</div>
<div class="bottom-on-last-page"><b>bottom-on-last-page</b></div>

Sandbox
P.S. I've studied similar topics here. The community had no answers to this question. Print Label at bottom of last page in Html

Try this:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Print Footer Example</title>
<style>
  @media print {
    .footer {
      position: fixed;
      bottom: 0;
    }
    .page-break {
      page-break-after: always;
    }
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<!-- Your content goes here -->
<div class="page-break"></div>

<!-- Footer block -->
<div class="footer">
  This is the footer.
</div>

</body>
</html>


in your case, the footer will be located on each page. It is necessary that when printing the footer is only on the last page
